# Change positions of chars in text-line using StringBuilder

Tags: java

I have a little struggle with function which I have to do.

Function get from user-input any random line of text and move all chars number of positions given in function. Result is saving to text file... and function checks if this move was positive (plus/additional).

I assume it should be done with StringBuilder followed with method charAt(index) and probably with loop but, I tried it and I have no idea how to manage it properly.

I have problem only with this chars move and check, here is result what I manage to do;

```
    public static void moveChars(int numberOfMovesForChar)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.println("Insert any line of text: ");
        String line = in.nextLine();

        // move all chars number of position given from user input and check 
        //if it is positive 


        PrintWriter out = null;
        try
        {
            File file = new File("filePath");
            if (!(file.exists()))
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

            out.println(/* moved 'text-line' to save in file */);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any help and suggestions! Cheers!

For example: (int numberOfMovesForChar = 2)

Input: "today"

Output: " __today"

where _ it's just a space, in this sample every char is moved 2 position to the right and I guess it's positive move, and from other side it could be

input: "today"

output: "day"

and here chars are moving to the left and cut off. I hope now it's able to understand :)

Comment: Unable to understand what are you actually trying to do. Please provide a sample input and output.

Comment: For example: (int numberOfMovesForChar = 2)  Input: "today" --> Output: "  __today", where _ it's just a space, in this sample every char is moved 2 position to the right and I guess it's positive move, and from other side it could be input: "today" --> output: "day" and here chars are moving to the left and cut off. I hope now it's able to understand :)

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments, so that all information is in one place. Not all comments may be visible initially.

Comment: First tell how will you process the input to output i.e how will "today"

become " __today" ?

Comment: I think about something like that; when we get input (String line) using charAt(index) and loop we can get to every index of this String and iterate this index with value from numberOfMoveForChar, so it will be smth like: "cat" --> indexes (1=c, 2=a, 3=t) and i.e int numberOfMoveForChar = 2, so we iterate (1+2=c, 2+2=a, 3+2=t) and output should be "  cat". It's even do able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an initial remark: a single method should deal with one single operation and/or delegate other concerns to other method. Here your method:

- reads a string
- modifies the string in a not trivial way (a way you do not know how to implement)
- writes the modified string.

My advice is to write a simple method that only *moves* a string and use it in your method: you will then be able to test individually the moving.

Code could be:

```
public static void moveChars(int numberOfMovesForChar)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println("Insert any line of text: ");
    String line = in.nextLine();

    // move all chars number of position given from user input and check 
    //if it is positive 


    PrintWriter out;
    try
    {
        File file = new File("filePath");
        if (!(file.exists()))
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

        out.println(move(line, numberOfMovesForChar));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String move(String orig, int moves) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (moves == 0) {               // take a copy
        builder.append(orig);
    }
    else if (moves > 0) {           // add initial spaces
        for (int i=0; i< moves; i++) {
            builder.append(' ');
        }
        builder.append(orig);
    }
    else {
        builder.append(orig.substring(-moves));    // copy a substring
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```